# Unable to receive scrape result after hosting on heroku

Tags: heroku

I hosted a telegram bot on heroku using webhook. It servers to scrape lyrics off a website. When I run the bot on my local machine, it is able to do so, however, when its hosted on Heroku, it keeps returning me element not found (I use beautiful soup). I have used different user-agents but to no avail. Any idea why?

Comment: It can really be anything. It would be more useful if you debug where exactly it fails and include the error messages and/or **what it sees when requesting a website**. If I were to make a guess is you are getting HTTP 403 Access forbidden. A lot of websites have Heroku servers on the banned server list because of people not respecting API limits or doing scraping.

Comment: thanks @TinNguyen I figured that would be the reason, in that case Ill have my bot on a remote server then, thanks!